# How Do I move the border wall without moving the text?

Tags: css

[as you can see the border right is all the way at the right of the header I want to move it closer to the middle text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vAGF.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRYwR.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9l2t.png)

```
 #header {
font-family: "NotoNashkArabic", "ProximaNova-regular", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
background-color: #2E7061;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
}


 #title {
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding:10px 5px 20px 5px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   margin: -.1px;
   font-size: 1.7em;
   border-right: 1px solid white;
 }
```

html

```
<body>
     <div id="header">
     <img src="Capture1.png"/>
     <p id="title">THE Text</p>


     </div>
     </body>
```

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant HTML markup, too.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add this to your css #title

```
display: inline-block;
```

which will be,

```
#title {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding:10px 5px 20px 5px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin: -.1px;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
```

I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not enough to reproduce what you show in the image. But I'll assume your image is floated left for now.

```css
    #header {
      font-family: "NotoNashkArabic", "ProximaNova-regular", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #2E7061;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
    }
    #header img{ 
      float: left;
    }
    #title {
      color: white;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin: -.1px;
      font-size: 1.7em;
      border-right: 1px solid white;
      width: 50%;
      margin-left: 200px;
      height: 100%;
      line-height:80px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x80.png">
    <p id="title">THE Text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I did here was:

- Set `width: 50%` on your `#title`. (Arbitrary value)
- I set the left margin to the width of your image (I guessed at 200px.) The reason is because the picture overlaps the width of the <p>-tag when the image is floated. I consider it more concise to have the values without overlap.
- I aligned the text right to get it close to the border. Use 'padding-right' to control the space between text and border.
- I removed vertical padding and set the line-height to the height of the header/image to get the text vertically centered and the border to reach from top to bottom of the header.

---

#### Other things to note:

```
margin-right: 20px;  // This has no meaning...
margin: -.1px;       // ...since it gets overridden by this.
```